# how to resize image dimension when browser resize?

Tags: jquery, html, image, responsive-design, window-resize

I am tired of searching for html image tag dimension. I make my website fully responsive. Image and divs of the website are re-sized according to screen size. When I checked my website in google page speed, it asks me to specify image dimension in html. I cann't make image dimension responsive. When I search in google, many suggest it isn't necessary in html if you define image width and height in css. But google page speed warns when I remove image dimension. I write code according

**CSS**

```
    #topbar section{
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
display:block;
}

#topbar section img{
    width:100%;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="topbar">
<section>   
<img src="example.jpg" alt="">
</section>
</div>
```

I am able to fix this issue in desktop size using following code.

```
echo "<section><img src='../add/$add' width="985" height="100" alt='$add'></section>";
```

but how to change image dimension dynamically when browser re-sizing ? When I resize browser, Google page speed insights warns like this according browser width.

```
http://krishisansar.com/add/news.gif is resized in HTML or CSS from 985x100 to 729x74. Serving a scaled image could save 79.7KiB (46% reduction).
```

Neither media queries works in this case, nor percentage worked within html width and height attribute. I cannot change pixel values of img tag. So I try to change px values from jquery. I know it is also usefulness. But is it possible to fix according following code or any way like this ?

```
<script>
var windowWidth = $("section#add").width();
var windowHeight = $("section#add").height();
$('#yourImgID').attr('width',windowWidth);
$('#yourImgID').attr('height',windowHeight);
</script>
```

It means I want to access width and height of section which contains image and attr to this section image which has yourImgID attribute. While resize browser, image size will be automatically decreased.
I found many suggestion using media queries regarding this case. Media query fits images in browser, but dimension can't be decreased. How can I change image dimension dynamically ? Suggestion and ideas are heartily welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the google page speed insights with a grain of salt. They aren't always practical.

Google is suggesting that if you're going to set a size of 729x74, you should save the image at that resolution instead of sending them a larger image and scaling it down.

Google also offers a PageSpeed module for apache and nginx if that's an option: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module

This module will do some of these optimizations on the server before it sends content to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Change your image to be the `background-image` of a div, then that `div` should automatically scale.

```
#yourDivWithBackground {
    background-image: url(url/to/your/image.png);
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Note that your `div` should be responsive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your tricks work. but one downside is it increase inline css too much. Images are dynamic, I mean images are generated from php code. So there is no option of using inline css